# How to add multiple lines to the end of file using bash?

Tags: bash, config, cat

I would like to add this code to the end of a file:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
            -T localhost:6082 \
            -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
            -S /etc/varnish/secret \
            -s malloc,256m"
```

How can I do this while keeping the structure and slashes?

I tried using `echo` line by line as well as this without success:

```
  cat > /etc/default/varnish  <<- EOM
  DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
            -T localhost:6082 \
            -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
            -S /etc/varnish/secret \
            -s malloc,256m"
  EOM
```

Answer (score 2):

Use quotes around here-doc identifier to avoid *shell expansion*:

```
cat >> /etc/default/varnish <<-'EOM'
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \                                                                                                                                   -T localhost:6082 \
            -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
            -S /etc/varnish/secret \
            -s malloc,256m"
EOM
```

As per `man bash`:

If any characters in word are **quoted**, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the
       here-document are not expanded.

Comment: Doesn't OP want `>>` ("to end of file")?

Comment: Thanks, Yes indeed `>>` should be used for appending to a file.

Comment: If I apply like this: 
#!/bin/bash

  cat >> /etc/default/varnish  >>-'EOM'
  DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
            -T localhost:6082 \
            -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
            -S /etc/varnish/secret \
            -s malloc,256m"
  EOM
I can see that the terminal just hangs without any error until I terminate it.

Comment: Make sure ending `EOM` is on a separate line and there is no space/tab before ending `EOM`